# how to format data in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have a little problem with formatting data from a PROC SQL on SAS 
I want to make an extraction of several columns but specifying the position of each column and the length for example:

```
number (position 0 , length 10, fill the rest with zero on the right)
Name ( position 11 , length 20 , fill the rest with spaces on the right)
Date ( position 21 , length 8 , delete "/" between DD MM YYYY) ......
```

Thank you

```
proc sql; 
create table CC as 
select SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) , 
    pmin.DANAIS, 
    pmin.CDNSDPTZ, 
    pmin.NNSCMNZ, 
    pmin.NOADR, 
    pmin.SIREN, 
    pmin.NIC, 
    pmin.NOM_PAT, 
    amin.LBLGMTPL, 
    amin.NOVOIE, 
    amin.CDTYVOI, 
    amin.LIBVOIE, 
    amin.LIBLD, 
    amin.CDPOST, 
    amin.LBLCDST, 
    amin.CDINSDPT, 
    amin.NINSCMN 
from sasuser.toto 
inner join saspcmb.pmin on SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) = ident 
inner join saspcmb.amin on SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) = ident ; 
quit;
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: here is my request and I want to format each column to have a file well organized `proc sql; create table CC as select SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) , pmin.DANAIS, pmin.CDNSDPTZ, pmin.NNSCMNZ, pmin.NOADR, pmin.SIREN, pmin.NIC, pmin.NOM_PAT, amin.LBLGMTPL, amin.NOVOIE, amin.CDTYVOI, amin.LIBVOIE, amin.LIBLD, amin.CDPOST, amin.LBLCDST, amin.CDINSDPT, amin.NINSCMN from sasuser.toto inner join saspcmb.pmin on SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) = ident inner join saspcmb.amin on SUBSTRING(Num_Compte from 16 for 8) = ident ; quit;`

Comment: I don't see the link between your question and the code. There are no fields `number`, `name` and `date`

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get those specific formats:

**1. `number (position 0 , length 10, fill the rest with zero on the right)`**

**Equates to:**

`input(substr(column, 1, 10), 10.)*(10**10/10**countc(substr(column, 1, 10),'','D'))`

SAS has a leading zero format but does not have a trailing zero format. You can pad the number of zeroes with the formula below:

`[Number]*(10^[Pad Length]/10^[Length of Number])`

**2. `Name ( position 11 , length 20 , fill the rest with spaces on the right)`**

**Equates to:**

`substr(column, 11, 20) length=20`

**3. `Date ( position 21 , length 8 , delete "/" between DD MM YYYY)`**

**Equates to:**

`tranwrd(substr(column, 21, 8), '/', ' ')`

Comment: I want to thank you for your answers and I think it works only on SAS and not on Proc sql because I tested nothing works

Comment: You are welcome! I found an issue with [1] in `proc sql` and updated the code. I used a test program and confirmed that it was producing values as expected. You may need to modify the `substr()` functions or add test cases in case numeric values are not returned from your data. If strings are shorter than expected, have non-numeric values when pulled in with `substr()`, etc., then it will break the above process. In those cases, you'll need to change the length returned to be where digits end. More complex logic like this would be better done in a `data` step.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `Z10.` format
2. SAS will left pad by default. You can control the alignment in other ways so there's no real value in doing this. But you could just use `PUT(var, format -l)` to left align the value.
3. Use `ddmmyyB10.` as your format.